# Can't select or edit a curve in Edit mode

Tags: vertices, select

I now can't select or edit a curve in blender in Edit mode. I could before, but now I can't. I must have hit some key that changed a setting. In object mode I can select it, move, rotate and scale it, but can't do anything with it in Edit mode. I have even uninstalled the program and reinstalled it again but it did not fix the problem. This happens in a project I am working on now with curves that used to work but don't now. Even starting a blank new project gets the same result. Mouse is set for left-click select. I have searched the web for an answer and can't find one. I really hope that someone has an answer to my problem.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Hello :). Please add some images and perhaps [share a .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I figured it out. Too embarrassed to say what I was doing wrong :) Thanks anyways. I am sure I will have more questions in the future.

Comment: Glad you made it work :).